# Javascript: How do I increment my variable by 1 onclick?

Tags: javascript, variables, increment

I have a 2d array of images called "onClickCard",

What I'm trying to do is make is so that every time I click one of the images in the 2d array I increment my variable called "click" by 1.

running the following:

```
    var click = 0; 
    var click=onclick.click+1
```

I just get a console error stating "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null:
onClickCard, 
onclick"

edits:

I tried the below suggestion of

```
var click = 0;
window.onclick=function(){click ++;}
```

and each click is still returning 0.

Comment: You can't click a variable! Your code is trying to do that...

Comment: click+=1; inside your onClick function would do it.  You need to have a onClick function for the element being clicked..

Comment: Which browser did you use? This is the same code but with alert() and you can click anywere, please try http://jsfiddle.net/Bum6L/2/show/

Answer (score 1):

You can't click on variables, you can add event/click listeners on elements. Since you don't refer any element I assume `window` on my example and attach a click event listener on it that runs a function were the `click` variable is added `+1`.

Try this:

```
var click = 0; 
window.onclick=function(){click ++;}
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bum6L/)**

Comment: @user2825148, in jsfiddle you need to click inside the window on the right-left. I tried it before posting.

Comment: @user2825148, here is the same but with alert(), just click anywere - http://jsfiddle.net/Bum6L/2/show/

Comment: Thanks guys this has helped me to progress a bit especially your jsfiddle link.